# What are those half-vanes in the engine inlet of a 707-328?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification, inlet, boeing-707

I just saw this:

[image]
[Source](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Air-France/Boeing-707-328/108385/L)

They look like IGVs but I'm not sure. What could those be? Do you know the engine?

Comment: Another [view](http://www.leteckemotory.cz/motory/nk-8/il62_12.jpg) from [this page](http://www.leteckemotory.cz/motory/nk-8/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a very interesting find there! It is in fact not an engine from a B707, but a [Kuznetsov NK-8](http://www.leteckemotory.cz/motory/nk-8/index.php) from Russia.

It was used in [Ilyushin Il-62 and Tupolev Tu-154 aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuznetsov_NK-8).

As for the intermediate vanes, it is my understanding that their purpose is no more special, than to just stabilize the airflow entering the bypass section of the engine.

[image: NK-8]
(Picture taken from the site from the first link in this answer)

Comment: Yes. This (both the stub and full vanes) is called IGV (Inlet Guide Vanes). Evidently, stabilising the flow around the tips was considered more important.

Comment: Older jet engines probably were more critical about the flow characteristics, adding those half vanes keeps the distance between vanes more equal.